# Working on a piece of code to convert numbers into base

Tags: python, math

First, I'm a newbie and trying my best, so be understanding.

I am working on an assignment for a class:

○ Asks the user a number as a string (to set a maximum number of digits in your program is ok);

○ Your program should ask which is the base (an Integer from 2 to 16);

○ With that information, your program should compute the binary and decimal representations of the number, then print it out as a string

○ For example, if the user enters: FA and 16, your program should print out:

-- "FA in base 16 is: 250 in base 10 and 11111010 in base 2"

○ If the user enters: 34 and 5, your program should print:

-- "34 in base 5 is: 19 in base 10 and 10011 in base 2"

What I have so far by working with both a tutor and a friend is this:

```
n = str(input ("Enter A Number between 2 and 16"))

while(True):
  in_num = str(input("What is the base?:" ))
  if in_num not in range(2,16):
    print(“enter a valid number between 2 and 16”)
  else:
print(bin(dec), "in binary.")
print(oct(dec), "in octal.")
print(hex(dec), "in hexadecimal.")

    
“”.join(f”{ord(i):08b}” for i in str
Float()

   print (n, "in base", in_num, is"" )  ]]
```

I believe from my conversations with my tutor that I have to also include lines of code for ternary, quaternary, etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried running this on Replit but it has a syntax error that I'm unable to detect.

Comment: please format the code properly by using single ` for inline code and ``` for blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def convert_to_decimal(number, base):
    decimal = 0
    power = len(number) - 1
    for digit in number:
        if digit.isdigit():
            value = int(digit)
        else:
            value = ord(digit.upper()) - ord('A') + 10
        decimal += value * (base ** power)
        power -= 1
    return decimal

n = input("Enter a number between 0 and 9 or A and F: ")
base = int(input("Enter the base (between 2 and 16): "))

decimal_representation = convert_to_decimal(n, base)
binary_representation = bin(decimal_representation)[2:]

print(f"{n} in base {base} is: {decimal_representation} in base 10 and {binary_representation} in base 2.")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `int(s, base)` for all practical purposes. It supports bases up to 36, so `int('python', 36)` is 1570137287.

Now to convert the string representation from base to decimal, first we need an alphabet. We need a list of digits so that we can give a digit for each numerical value below the base and look up the alphabet to know the value associated with the digit. Hexadecimal uses digits 0123456789 plus abcdef, there are 26 letters in the basic Latin alphabet, if we use all letters we can convert numbers up to base 36.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits

ALPHABET = digits + ascii_lowercase
```

The above creates the string `'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'` and assigns it to `ALPHABET`. We can use `ALPHABET.index(c)` to convert the digit representation back to numerical value.

Then observe the number 123456789, it is equal to 1 * 10<sup>8</sup> + 2 * 10<sup>7</sup> + 3 * 10<sup>6</sup> + 4 * 10<sup>5</sup> + 5 * 10<sup>4</sup> + 6 * 10<sup>3</sup> + 7 * 10<sup>2</sup> + 8 * 10<sup>1</sup> + 9 * 10<sup>0</sup>, from left to right, the power of the place value decreases. The leftmost place has the most power, it is equal to the length of the string minus one, and each subsequent place has one less power, until the last place has power 0.

The same number in binary is `111010110111100110100010101`.

It means:

1 * 2<sup>26</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>25</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>24</sup> +
0 * 2<sup>23</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>22</sup> +
0 * 2<sup>21</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>20</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>19</sup> +
0 * 2<sup>18</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>17</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>16</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>15</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>14</sup> +
0 * 2<sup>13</sup> +
0 * 2<sup>12</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>11</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>10</sup> +
0 * 2<sup>9</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>8</sup> +
0 * 2<sup>7</sup> +
0 * 2<sup>6</sup> +
0 * 2<sup>5</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>4</sup> +
0 * 2<sup>3</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>2</sup> +
0 * 2<sup>1</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>0</sup>

Get rid of where the places have no value:

1 * 2<sup>26</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>25</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>24</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>22</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>20</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>19</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>17</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>16</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>15</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>14</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>11</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>10</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>8</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>4</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>2</sup> +
1 * 2<sup>0</sup>

The numerical values are:

67108864 +
33554432 +
16777216 +
4194304 +
1048576 +
524288 +
131072 +
65536 +
32768 +
16384 +
2048 +
1024 +
256 +
16 +
4 +
1

The number 123456789 in hexadecimal is much more compact:

75bcd15:

7 * 16<sup>6</sup> +
5 * 16<sup>5</sup> +
b * 16<sup>4</sup> +
c * 16<sup>3</sup> +
d * 16<sup>2</sup> +
1 * 16<sup>1</sup> +
5 * 16<sup>0</sup>

The terms are:

7 * 16777216 +
5 * 1048576 +
b * 65536 +
c * 4096 +
d * 256 +
1 * 16 +
5 * 1

(b has a numeric value of 11, c = 12 and d = 13)

So to convert a number from any base to decimal (I have to add this is wrong terminology, numbers don't have any digits, numerals have, you are interpreting numeral to get numeric value), reverse the order of the string representation, go from left to right, assign indexes to the first element 0 and the second 1 et cetera, for each element, query `ALPHABET` to get value of digit, multiply the value by the base raised to the index, and then sum, done.

Example implementation:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits

ALPHABET = digits + ascii_lowercase

def interpret_numeral(numeral, base):
    return sum(ALPHABET.index(digit) * base ** index for index, digit in enumerate(numeral[::-1]))
```

Example usage:

```
interpret_numeral('111010110111100110100010101', 2)
#123456789

interpret_numeral('726746425', 8)
#123456789

interpret_numeral('123456789', 10)
#123456789

interpret_numeral('75bcd15', 16)
#123456789
```

If you want to get the numerical value of `'21i3v9'` in base 36 for example, use `interpret_numeral('21i3v9', 36)`, if you don't get any output, try using `print(interpret_numeral('21i3v9', 36))`, it should return `123456789`.

To convert a number to a base (to represent the numeric value in a base), we can repeatedly divide the number by base, assign the whole part to the number and get the remainder, until the number is 0.

This will get the digits in reverse order, we then need to reverse the string.

Operation for interpreting 123456789 in decimal:

```
123456789 = 12345678 * 10 + 9
12345678 = 1234567 * 10 + 8
1234567 = 123456 * 10 + 7
123456 = 12345 * 10 + 6
12345 = 1234 * 10 + 5
1234 = 123 * 10 + 4
123 = 12 * 10 + 3
12 = 1 * 10 + 2
1 = 0 * 10 + 1
```

Hexadecimal:

```
123456789 = 7716049 * 16 + 5
7716049 = 482253 * 16 + 1
482253 = 30140 * 16 + 13
30140 = 1883 * 16 + 12
1883 = 117 * 16 + 11
117 = 7 * 16 + 5
7 = 0 * 16 + 7
```

We have the numeric digits at this point. All we need to do is then lookup `ALPHABET` to convert to associated string:

```
def base_represent(number, base):
    string = ''
    while number:
        number, digit = divmod(number, base)
        string = ALPHABET[digit] + string
    return string
```

Example usage:

```
for base in range(2, 37):
    print(base_represent(123456789, base))
```

Output:

```
111010110111100110100010101
22121022020212200
13112330310111
223101104124
20130035113
3026236221
726746425
277266780
123456789
63762a05
35418a99
1c767471
12579781
ac89bc9
75bcd15
51g2a21
3b60f89
2bg64ae
1ibc1j9
194gh7f
11l0805
j43jfb
fc2egl
cg15le
aa44a1
8g86ni
74nqb1
60fshj
52ce69
49l302
3lnj8l
353c3r
2od2i1
2c9g1t
21i3v9
```